# Making a neighbour list of cones

Tags: python

I have a nested list of junctions between cones.

```
a = [0,1]
b = [2,4]
c = [2,0]
d = [4,3]
e = [6,3]

f=[a,b,c,d,e]
```

I want to write a program that lists every neighbour of cone 0, every neighbour of cone 1... ie i want the output to be

```
[[1,2],[0],[0,4],[4,6],[2,3],[],[3]]
```

Notice cone 5 is empty because it has no neighbours.

The program I have is the following:

```
 neighbour_list = {}

 for x, y in e:
   neighbour_list.setdefault(x, [])
   neighbour_list[x].append(y)
   neighbour_list.setdefault(y, [])
   neighbour_list[y].append(x)
 neighbour_list = list(neighbour_list.values())
 print(neighbour_list)
```

Yet the output does not print neighbours for cone 5 it just skips it:

```
 [[1, 2], [0], [4, 0], [4, 6], [2, 3], [3]]
```

How can I make it print an empty list for cone 5 ?

thanks

Comment: What exactly is a "junction between cones" and how does it relate to your lists of integers? What do the values in your `a`, `b`, `c`, etc lists mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a list of edges (cone intersections) in a graph and you're trying to find the lists of neighbors for each of the graph vertices (the cones themselves). The issue you're having is that some vertices have no edges, and so they don't appear in your list.

The best way to solve this is to build your list differently from the dictionary you've created with the neighbor lists. Rather than just turning `neighbor_list.values()` into a list, you really need to iterate over it by the specific vertex keys you want to consider. This way, you'll get a default value for any value that doesn't have any edges (and you'll get them in a well-defined order, rather than the arbitrary (though tending to sequential, for integer keys) order you get from the `dict` data structure.

Try making your next to last line be:

```
neighbor_list = [neighbor_list.get(x, []) for x in range(7)]
```

Adjust the `range` parameter as necessary to cover the vertices you need to account for. Also, consider using a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module, which will build lists automatically for you rather than messing around with `dict.setdefault` and `dict.get`.